# Failed to start server with mysql configuration in Grails-3.0.8

Tags: mysql, grails

I tried to connect grails-3.0.8 version to mysql as my database. BuildConfig.groovy is been replaced by application.yml in this version. However, after my configuration with mysql, I cannot start the grails server anymore using command line. What is wrong with my configuration? Please help. It is my first time working with grails. Here is the application.yml code

```
---
grails:
profile: web
codegen:
    defaultPackage: mygrails
info:
app:
    name: '@info.app.name@'
    version: '@info.app.version@'
    grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
groovy:
    template:
        check-template-location: false

---
grails:
mime:
    disable:
        accept:
            header:
                userAgents:
                    - Gecko
                    - WebKit
                    - Presto
                    - Trident
    types:
        all: '*/*'
        atom: application/atom+xml
        css: text/css
        csv: text/csv
        form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        html:
          - text/html
          - application/xhtml+xml
        js: text/javascript
        json:
          - application/json
          - text/json
        multipartForm: multipart/form-data
        pdf: application/pdf
        rss: application/rss+xml
        text: text/plain
        hal:
          - application/hal+json
          - application/hal+xml
        xml:
          - text/xml
          - application/xml
urlmapping:
    cache:
        maxsize: 1000
controllers:
    defaultScope: singleton
converters:
    encoding: UTF-8
views:
    default:
        codec: html
    gsp:
        encoding: UTF-8
        htmlcodec: xml
        codecs:
            expression: html
            scriptlets: html
            taglib: none
            staticparts: none
---
hibernate:
cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

endpoints:
jmx:
    unique-names: true

dataSource:
pooled: true
jmxExport: true
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

environments:
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: create-drop
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/grails_db;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        username: root
        password:
test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/grails_db;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/grails_db;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 50
            minIdle: 5
            maxIdle: 25
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Command line error

[image]

Comment: what is --stacktrace, --debug, --info giving you?  or is this remaining ...83 more the stacktrace (which would be the most interesting part - instead of all that fancy colours). also please don't add screenshots of error logs.  they are impossible to search.

Comment: Please see updated image. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the url below

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/grails_db;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

to

```
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/grails_db
```

and add the code below to your **build.gradle** file

```
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
```